# There is an error in the bulletin board number created with ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
            @{
                int i = 0;
                int idx = 0;
            }
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.OnePageOfList)
            {
                idx = ViewBag.OnePageOfList.Count - i;
                String str = "공지사항";
                if (@item.Category.Equals(str))
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>@idx.ToString()</td>
                        <td>@item.Category</td>
                        <td><a href="/Board/Detail?aidx=@item.ArticleIDX">@item.Title</a></td>
                        <td>
                            @if (@item.ModifyMemberID == item.Members.ID)
                        {
                            @item.Members.Name;
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>@Convert.ToDateTime(item.ModifyDate).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")</td>
                </tr>

                }
                i++;
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="btnCreate()" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str">글쓰기</button>
</div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
     @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfList, page => Url.Action("Notice", new { page })) 
  </div>
```

idx = board Number

Only 1.2.3.4.5 will be repeated.

My bulletin board becomes paging when more than five articles are written.
If there are seven articles registered on page 1, page 7.6.5.4.3 on page 2, it is normal to do so.
However, if there are 7 articles currently, it will go up to 1 page 5 4 3 2 1 2 page 2 1.
How do I fix idx?

Comment: Can you state your issue in simple words, whatever you have explained is really messy and confusing.

Comment: I solved that problem. Thank you for your interest.